# Time calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 starttime=(new Date()).getTime();
 endtime=(new Date()).getTime();

 (endtime-starttime )/1000
```

will give a value.What is this value and why is it divided by 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in this particular case the value will be 0.

you need to divide it by 1000 because time is represented in miliseconds, so to get the seconds you need to perform the transformation `1s = 1000ms`

Answer (score 1):

That code is calculating the number of seconds that have elapsed between two dates. The division by 1000 is there because the `getTime()` method returns a value measured in millseconds.

The code is actually needlessly long-winded. To get the milliseconds that have elapsed between two `Date` objects, you can just use the `-` operator on the `Date`s themselves:

```
var start = new Date();

// Some code that takes some time

var end = new Date();
var secondsElapsed = (end - start) / 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) gives the number of milliseconds since 1970 (Epoch)

Divide the difference by 1000 and you get seconds

Comment: you mean epoch, and `new Date()` returns the current time, not the epoch by default.

Comment: new Date().getTime() does. Fixed era

Answer (score 0):

value=millisecond delta, it is divided to turn the delta into seconds